# Trouble Filtering in PostgreSQL With Recursive CTE Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, common-table-expression

I am having trouble formulating a query to meet the following criteria (have a basic CTE query working) but am thinking I am missing/overlooking something and am hoping SO can help (much appreciated in advance!). I've tried looking at some of the other SO posts about recursive CTE's, but unfortunately don't feel like I've been able to answer my question(s) while following along with those posts.

Given a `categories` table with the following columns:

```sql
    `id` int - primary key
    `limit_to` text[] - array of text / is nullable
    `parent_id` int - references `id` / is nullable
    
    with values:
    
    id | limit_to | parent_id
    -------------------------
    1  | {'tc'}   | null
    -------------------------
    2  | null     | 1
    -------------------------
    3  | null     | 2
    -------------------------
    4  | null     | null
    -------------------------
    5  | {'ta'}   | null
```

I am trying to write a query that will filter out records (parent/child associated) having `limit_to IS NOT NULL`. In this instance, I would expect rows `1,2,3` and `5` to be filtered out, as 1 has a `limit_to` value of `{'tc'}` and its descendants are `2` and `3`, respectively. Row `5` also has a value that isn't null `{'ta'}`. So in this case only row `4` would be returned in the final select.

Query I've tried so far:

```sql
with recursive tree as (
  (
    select 
      * 
    from 
      categories 
    where 
      limit_to is null
  ) 
  union all 
    (
      select 
        categories.* 
      from 
        categories 
        inner join tree on tree.id = categories.parent_id 
      where 
        tree.limit_to is null
    )
) 
select 
  id, 
  parent_id 
from 
  categories 
where 
  id in (
    select 
      id 
    from 
      tree
  ) 
  and limit_to is null 
order by 
  id asc
```

However with this example query, I am still seeing the descendants of row `1` (`2` and `3`), even though they are recursive children on `parent_id = 1`, which is being filtered out because its `limit_to` record has a value. I have a feeling I am missing placing an additional `WHERE` filter expression, but am not entirely sure on where that is.

I was also working on a query to match where `limit_to IS NULL OR '''tc''' = ANY(limit_to)` to match on records only having that criteria (so in this case row `5` would be eliminated/not returned, and the other records would return), but I have a feeling I can't get that query working fully until I understand what condition I am missing for filtering entirely on where `limit_to IS NULL` and ensuring child rows are properly filtered out.

I greatly appreciate any insight on what I might be missing / any pointers ( but not null :P ) in the right direction on how to get the queries properly filtering as I would expect based on what I describe above. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you walk the tree recursively, you need to keep some sort of flag which denotes whether or not an instance of `categories.limit_to is not null` has been seen in any parent records to the current record. This flag is updated at every `join` to be `true` if the new record has `categories.limit_to is not null`. Then, when you query from the `cte`, you can simply scan for records containing a flag of `false`:

```
with recursive cte as (
   select c.*, c.limit_to is not null f from categories c where c.parent_id is null
   union all
   select c.*, c1.f or c.limit_to is not null f from cte c1 
   join categories c on c.parent_id = c1.id
)
select id, limit_to, parent_id from cte where not f
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/O4ISRdLO).

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked as expected and got back correct results from the actual table that I am using, as I was expecting!

Comment: Is it possible to do 2 flags, so if I wanted where `limit_to is null f, '''tc''' = any(limit_to) t`, it would return the tree recursively where both criteria is met? I believe I mentioned in second to last paragraph above e.g.
`with recursive cte as (
   select c.*, c.limit_to is null f, '''tc''' = any(limit_to) t from categories c where c.parent_id is null
   union all
   select c.*, c1.f or c.limit_to is null f, '''tc''' = any(c.limit_to) t from cte c1 
   join categories c on c.parent_id = c1.id
)
select id, limit_to, parent_id from cte where f or t;
`

Comment: @Woodrow To clarify, you would be attempting to return results from the query where `'tc'` does not occur in any parent/children?

Comment: Sorry about that. To clarify, I would want to return any parent/children where limit_to contains TC OR limit_to is null, excluding any other records where limit_to may contain something other than TC or null. Thank you!

Comment: Think I figured it out (modified your existing fiddle - https://dbfiddle.uk/jE6NXmdK)

Comment: @Woodrow Apologies for the delay in response! Your fiddle looks correct, but let me know how it goes

Comment: No worries! Seems to be working correctly for my needs under actual DB/table. Thanks again!

Comment: @Woodrow Great to hear!